# Aleatorizando dois conjuntos de números, não repetindo os valores dentro de cada grupo (R)

Tags: r, dplyr, números-aleatórios

Considerando que eu tenho esses individuos em um arquivo:

```
ID
1
1
1
3
3
3
7
7
7
```

E eu preciso atribuir dois conjuntos de números a ID de forma aleatória `(set1 - 1,2,3; set2 - 5,15,25)`.
Pra fazer isso minha tentativa foi:

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(set1=sample(c(1,2,3), size=n(), replace=F)) %>%
  ungroup()
  dplyr::mutate(set2=sample(c(5,15,25), size=n(), replace=F)) %>%
  ungroup ()
```

e obtive isso:

```
ID  set1 set2
1   1   15
3   1   25
7   1   25
1   2   5
3   2   15
7   2   5
1   3   25
3   3   5
7   3   15
```

mas eu preciso que o banco fique assim:

```
 ID  set1 set2
    1   1   15
    3   1   25
    7   1   5
    1   2   5
    3   2   15
    7   2   25
    1   3   25
    3   3   5
    7   3   15
```

Preciso que os valores não se repitam dentro dos grupos, estou tendo dificuldades para controlar duas variáveis ao mesmo tempo. Já tentei controlar usando `group_by(ID, set1)` tbm, mas estou apanhando. Alguma sugestão.Lembrando que preciso atribuir esses valores de forma aleatória. Obrigado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data.frame:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 7, 7, 7))
```

Pacote dyplr:

```
library(dplyr)
```

Separando o problema em 2.

Aqui criamos o set1 agrupado pelo ID:

```
df <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(set1 = sample(c(1, 2, 3), size = n(), replace = F)) %>%
  arrange(set1)
```

Aqui criamos o set2 agrupado pelo set1:

```
df <- df %>% group_by(set1) %>%
  mutate(set2 = sample(c(5, 15, 25), size = n(), replace = F))

df
```

Saída:

```
     ID  set1  set2
1     1     1    25
2     3     1    15
3     7     1     5
4     1     2    25
5     3     2     5
6     7     2    15
7     1     3     5
8     3     3    25
9     7     3    15
```